# Is there a way to check for the good amount of replicates for let's say T test or just mere One-Way anova (a priori)?

Tags: anova, t-test, sample-size, statistical-power

I have already asked this in Reddit but I really cannot find the answer
I know you can check for amount of sample sizes in G power but not really for experiments.

I can't be using a minimum of 100 replicates per group if I am testing efficacy of three fertilizers with medium effect size lol.

Also if replicates is different to sample size, how come we can use the same tests (let's say t test) to experimental units and sampling units if they don't follow the same concept? I know in essence they are different but statistically speaking?

I can use T-test to find difference between general weighted average of school 1 vs. school 2. I can also use t-test to find the difference between dry weight of lettuce after addition of fertilizer 1 and fertilizer 2. The first one is mere data collection while the other is experimentation. Yet I know I need large sample sizes in the first one and not that much replicates ( I reckon 5 is kinda acceptable don't you think? ) for the second one. Why is this so?

My understanding when it comes to computation(not concept) is that replicates per group/treatment = sample size per group. Is this wrong? Whenever I Google "replicates for t test" they always puts me to sample size search results. Even Google doesn't know the difference apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks about several different issues involving the power of various tests. I will try
to give some useful answers. (You might also want to look at other links on this site under 'Related' in the margin.)

Consider a two tailed, balanced, pooled two-sample t test (same sample size $n$ for each group and samples from normal populations with the same variance $\sigma^2).$ You will test $H_0: \mu_1=\mu_2$ against $H_a:\mu_1 \ne \mu_2.$

Then the power (probability of rejection when $\mu_1 \ne \mu_2$) depends on the significance level $\alpha$ (often chosen
to be 5%), the sample size $n,$ the common variance $\sigma^2,$ and the size of the specific difference $\Delta = |\mu_1 - \mu_1|$ to be detected.

Many mathematical statistics books and advanced books
on design of experiments have an exact formula
relating these quantities, which involves a
non-central t distribution.

If sample sizes differ, population variances differ, or a one-sided test is to be done, then
power computations are somewhat more intricate.
A Welch t test (not assuming equal variances)
has slightly lower power than a pooled t test
in case population variances are equal.

The following simulation in R finds the approximate power for the case $\alpha = 0.05, \sigma=5, \Delta = 4, n = 30.$ The method is to do 100,000 t tests
to these specifications and note the proportion of tests that reject $H_0.$ The approximate power is $86\%.$

```
set.seed(2022)
pv = replicate(10^5, 
      t.test(rnorm(30,50,5),rnorm(30,54,5),
      var.eq=T)$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.86067
```

*Notes:* (1) It turns out that the power for
a specified sample size is the same for any specific value of $\Delta/\sigma,$ if all other parameters remain the same.

(2) An unbalance test, with $n_1 \ne n_2,$ is somewhat less efficient. That is, other parameters being equal, a test with $n_1 = n_2 = 30$ has noticeably
higher power than a test with $n_1 = 15, n_2 = 45,$
which also uses $60$ subjects overall.

(3) Considerations for a one-factor ANOVA are similar. Formally, the power depends on $\theta = \frac 1 g
\sum_{i=1}^g (\mu_i -\bar\mu)^2,$ where there are
$g$ levels of the factor and $\bar\mu = \frac 1 g \sum_i \mu_i.$ But some 'power and sample size' procedures look at $\Delta = |\mu_i = \mu_{i^\prime}|,$ the largest difference among the $\mu_i$ that one wants to detect. If *ad hoc* comparisons of pairs of levels is envisioned, it is important to set $\Delta$ with that in mind.

Comment: Sorry I am not really familar with math thingies since my stat training is just JMP/R/SPSS go brr and just read the p-value. Now that the idea of power and sample size come in mind, this all looks very complicated.

Comment: In testing a hypothesis, there are two possible wrong decisions: (a) Reject $H_0$ when it's true and (b) fail to reject $H_0$ when it's false. Significance level, often set at 0.05 = 5% is probability of (a). Power often sought to be 80%, 90%, 95% (according to needs and budget) is probability of not making mistake (b) when $H_0$ false is interpreted to mean false in a particular way specified as a particular distance of the parameter from the value in $H_0.$ // Low sig level, Hight power, and small sample size are all "good". Any one experiment has to be designed to balance the three 'good's.